# How to auto-format AS3 variable declarations in alphabetical order?

Tags: actionscript-3, formatting, declaration, code-formatting, alphabetical

While coding, I wondered if a plugin exists that I could highlight a series of variable declarations, hit some special keyboard shortcut and BAM! They would appear in alphabetical order.

Is there anything that does this in Flash Builder? Or FlashDevelop even?

So it would go from this:

```
private var _value:Number;
private var _helloWorld:String;
private var _foobar:Boolean;
```

To this:

```
private var _foobar:Boolean;
private var _helloWorld:String;
private var _value:Number;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[FlexFormatter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/flexformatter/) is a plugin for Flash Builder and allows you to do this. You can enable it in the plugin's options ("AS rearranging"). Afterwards you can select the lines of code and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to format the selected lines.

You can install the plugin by adding the following update site to your Flash Builder (Eclipse):

> http://flexformatter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/FlexFormatter/FlexPrettyPrintCommandUpdateSite/

Comment: It has tons of really wicked features! Though I like the simplicity of FlashDevelop's "Sort By Groups", I think FlexFormatter will have more use in the large app I work on at my job :D. I might even recommend it to my fellow coworkers to eliminate those frustrated times where one developer doesn't like another one's coding style.

Comment: I usually just copy and paste into a word do and sort, FlexFormatter is soooo much cooler, thanks for the suggestion. 1+

Answer (score 1):

In FlashDevelop Highlight the variable lines and go Edit > SortLines.

Answer (score 1):

In FlashDevelop, you can select some text and go to *Edit -> Sort lines*.
There might even be a keyboard shortcut for it.

There also is the command *Sort line groups*, which is useful if you have separated variable groups.

```
private var _value1:Number;
private var _helloWorld1:String;
private var _foobar1:Boolean;

private var _value2:Number;
private var _helloWorld2:String;
private var _foobar2:Boolean;
```

results in

```
private var _foobar1:Boolean;
private var _helloWorld1:String;
private var _value1:Number;

private var _foobar2:Boolean;
private var _helloWorld2:String;
private var _value2:Number;
```

Comment: There is not! Unless you set it up yourself.